# More than one condition in drools spreadsheet

Tags: drools

I cannot correctly compile the spreadsheet in drools
The compiler say:
[10,1]: [ERR 102] Line 10:1 mismatched input 'then' in rule "Basic_12"
This is my table:
[image]

I tried to change the condition to country==$1 and name==$1 but the compiler say:
mismatched input '==' in rule "Basic_12"

I also tried to put $policy.country == $1 and $policy.name == $1
but remains

Note that the Object Types columns are merged as indicated in the documentation.

Comment: What are 'country' and 'name' floating around in B10 / C10? Perhaps they're supposed to be `$policy.country == $1` ?

Comment: Yes, country and name are Strings in the Policy object. But even specifying it in the constraint row doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: In the documentation ( https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/8.44.0.Final/drools-docs/drools/language-reference/index.html#decision-tables-defining-proc ) there are some tables as examples and my table is not so different from their

Comment: Decision tables are extremely non-performant and not very well documented, usually it's trial-and-error until you get it working. I would strongly suggest just writing DRL, or even using templates if you have multiple rules following common structures.